# C++ - Weird code output

Tags: c++

This code :

```
class A {
public:
    int _a;
    A():_a(0) { cout << "A default - ctor, ";}
    A(int i):_a(i) { cout << "A int - ctor, ";}
    operator int() { cout << "A int - operator, "; return 33;}
    virtual ~A() { cout << "A dtor, ";}
};
int main() {
    A* a = new A(99);
    cout << *a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the output to be :
**A int-operator, A int-ctor, 33**

but the true output is :
**A int-ctor, A int-operator, 33**

Comment: Why do you expect the operator to run before the constructor?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ how do you know that?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ but the output doesn't have any newlines in it... and it wouldn't even compile the way he had it.

Comment: @clcto The very 1st version had ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I don't understand your comment, nor why you'd rolled back the code (I didn't notice the history until after my edit, didn't mean to participate in an edit war).  Can you clarify why you think the original code was better?

Comment: @clcto what i expected is my answer
but the "true answer" is the official answer that the university staff published

Comment: @user3092193 okay, well you were wrong. this is what should happen. you create the object, so the constructor is called and that is output, then you dereference it, and it implicitly calls `operator int()` and then that is printed. it makes perfect sense. So the true output is right...

Comment: I'm surprised that this question has received so many upvotes. There isn't even any logical reason for the OP's expected output that I can decipher. "This question does not show any research effort" and is "not useful" both seem to apply.

Comment: @JBentley: One upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you call `"new A(99)"`, which invokes `"A(int i)"`, which prints `"A int - ctor, "`.

The following line calls `"cout << *a"`, which invokes `"operator int()"`, which prints `"A int - operator, "`.

Then the line complete with the `"cout << [result] << endl"`, which prints the result (33) and a newline.

So `"A int - ctor, "` + `"A int - operator, "` + `"33"` + `"endl"` is `"A int - ctor, A int - operator, 33"`.

Comment: @MooingDuck - Great point.  I changed it to "invokes" to avoid saying that he "calls" something which "calls" something.  Another option would have been "you write" rather than "you call".  Thanks!

Comment: @MooingDuck I still didn't understand how from ** cout <<*a ** it gets to the operator int()

Comment: @MooingDuck at the beginning i thought that i did understand and then i realized that i didn't

Comment: @user3092193 - "cout << *a" gets to "operator int()" because cout has no "operator <<(A)" explaining how to print an A, but cout does have an "operator <<(int)" and A has an "operator int()" so the compiler realizes that an A-to-int conversion will accomplish valid compilation of the code.